# iPad Simulator (4.3) crashes with dyld error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm running an application in an iPad Simulator (4.3) that crashes due to a missing symbol error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMetadataQuery
  Referenced from: /Users/Me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/B13BE6DF-61B9-4C23-98E7-BEC72330FF19/iPad.app/iPad
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
 in /Users/Me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/B13BE6DF-61B9-4C23-98E7-BEC72330FF19/iPad.app/iPad
```

At what point in the launch process does this error occur? I don't seem to be actually **executing** any code - I have placed breakpoints at both the locations where this class would be instantiated (which is **never** executed when version is < 5.0) and at the delegate method `applicationWillFinishLaunching:`

*But, the crash occurs before either points are hit.*

I know that the underlying issue is that the `NSMetadataQuery` class was added in iOS 5.0, but I would of course like to maintain backwards-compatibility with earlier versions. (I'm using the proper `NSClassFromString` calls.)

I have an iPhone application which uses `NSMetadataQuery` on iOS 5.0, and skips it if running 4.3 or lower, and works properly in the simulator. Thus, I'm confused as to why this particular program crashes.

*Does the `NSMetadataQuery` class actually exist in the iPhone version of iOS 4.2 and 4.3, but not in the iPad version? (And the API simply wasn't exposed until iOS 5.0?)*

Comment: Have you used  library file libdyld.dylib in iOS 5.0?? It may be the issue as this file is not available for version of iOS below 5.0

Comment: I honestly am not sure - how can I determine if I'm using this file? I don't explicitly remember adding it.

Comment: Are you using XCode version below 4.2?

Comment: Is your problem solved?? if not Please include a screenshot of your error log so anyone can have an dea in detail.

Comment: The problem is not solved. There is no additional error log aside from what I've already posted in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying issue was that the `Foundation` framework was strongly-linked in the iPad version of the application (that was crashing) and was weakly-linked in the iPhone version. (Which allowed the iPhone version to run without requiring those classes at linking time. Of course, calling/instantiating any of those classes on 4.X versions of the iPhone simulator would have similarly crashed.)

Problem was solved by changing (under the Project Info in Xcode) the dependency option of the `Foundation.framework` from *required* to *optional*.